# How to add type annotations for overridden initializer with *args and **kwargs?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pylance

I'm extending a class from a library (class `A`) that has a very long list of arguments (shortened here for readability). To avoid duplicating the entire base class `__init__` signature in my class I am using `*args` and `**kwargs`, however this erases the base class type information, making it more difficult to use my class downstream.

```py
class A:

  def __init__(self, a: int, b: str, c: float = 3.14, d: bool = False):
    # Library Initialization Logic
    pass


class B(A):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Supplemental Initialization Logic
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the past I have used and `ParamSpec` to annotate function decorators which use `*args` and `**kwargs` with `P.args` and `P.kwargs`, however PEP 612 does not seem applicable to this situation, so while the following is an acceptable use of `ParamSpec`:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')

def example(function: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
  def decorator(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
    # Logic here
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  return decorator
```

This is not, with Pylance producing the error `ParamSpec "P" has no meaning in this context`, and MyPy producing general errors about incompatible types. This makes sense, as there is nothing linking type information from class `A`'s initializer to `P`.

```py
P = ParamSpec('P')

class B(A):

  def __init__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
    # Supplemental Initialization Logic
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there any way to automatically copy the typing information in this situation without manually recreating the function signature?